# Running a SQL Server agent job continuously

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, sql-job

Can I set up a SQL Server agent job to run the same job continuously as soon as the previous instance is completed or after 5 minutes (whichever is higher)? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I think if a SQL Agent job is running and you attempt to run it again (either manually or via a schedule), [it won't run a second instance of the job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865042/will-a-sql-server-job-skip-a-scheduled-run-if-it-is-already-running).  So just set up a 5 min schedule for your job and let it roll.

Comment: Does it throw up an error if it re-runs when a previous instance is running?

Comment: You'll see an entry in the SQL log similar to this: `[000] Request to run job <your job name> (from User acme\jdoe) refused because the job already has a pending request from User acme\jdoe`.  If you if right-click the SQL Agent job in SSMS and view the job history, you won't see an entry for when the job attempted to run but did not.